# Embedded Redis in different machines

Tags: java, redis

I have a Java web application which is running in 5 servers i need to enhance the performance by adding Redis by using [embedded-redis](https://github.com/kstyrc/embedded-redis), but i have one concern .. Is it possible to use embedded-redis in my application ( which is deployed in multiple machines) and sharing the same data in all machines ( the same as the Redis server - cluster mode)?

what i found is how to start the embedded-redis in cluster mode in the same machine with different ports.